# SharePlum download file - File is a string?

Tags: python, sharepoint

I'm using [SharePlum](https://pypi.org/project/SharePlum/) and get_file method. It seems to have downloaded the file in string format. So when I print the file this is what I get.

```
    authcookie = Office365(config["sp_base_path"], username=config["sp_user"], password=config["sp_password"]).GetCookies()
    site = Site(config["sp_base_path"] + "/sites/portal/", version=Version.v365, authcookie=authcookie)
    folder = site.Folder('Shared Documents/tickets/' + ticketid)
    data = folder.get_file(request.GET["filename"])
    print(data)



IDATx��k�UW§�����ax�TF∟J�Td↕ML}Ԩ����Ą��☼�T�↕‼>�¶����GК@5Biڂ&&~�/���UiK�6FZ�@��t��;e`f��{�▼ι�{�9��������y�}��k����{�-4@US�↔▲◄�k
��^������#Q     .g�5$R6�♦����♂<�.��Τ�w♂���\I�►♠f*xD     &C�∟�▼��`�\Z b☺Xh t��♦o¶�‼X↔|n�H#�r↑Z♂��O�p}��7�☻�*Ot$�!"■0�e׼2��e`e��o2=L�#s►�!<����5�x�►Ӿ↓N�f�2☼��←<���S�������m�w∟gC�\>�n��ж☻N�f)�=►B!��El�♫J~�BDx7�(�¶�~B5�؎�8�     �m��v�∟�:▼0<����☻←§■$�B♣(�F�'���H♥q~"Rǻ�v
```

Answer (score 0):

The Explanation for this question is

Everything can be treated as bytes, so obviously everything is kind of string with encoding

What you are seeing is an `application/octet-stream` encoded string which can be a content of any file more specifically a binary file

try open a small `exe` from your computer in notepad++, don't change it, you can see similar content in it

If you want to save that content to a local file then you can use this python code

```
 with open('myfile.docx', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(data.encode())
        f.close()
```

If you want to use `SharePlum` API then use

```
folder.download_file('filename.txt')
```

Assuming filename.txt is a file uploaded in sharepoint

Comment: How do I convert it into a in memory file object?

Comment: do you want to save to hard disk ? is that what you mean memory file object ?

Comment: changed the answer, simply use `.encode()` to convert string to bytes

Comment: `folder.download_file('filename.txt')` Seems to have been removed. As it was replaced by get_file
`def get_file(self, file_name):
        response = self._session.get(self.site_url + f"/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('{self.info['d']['ServerRelativeUrl']}/{file_name}')/$value")
        return response.text`

Comment: the content seems to be an `iDAT` it is not the file, please double check the file URL

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. I removed the response.text and return response.content that gave me the in memory file. Thanks for helping me!